# Is there a way to have CloudFormation not replace an existing resource on update?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

This resource creates a beanstalk application version: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-version.html

Having that in a template is convenient and useful because the Beanstalk environment and the application version can be deployed at the same time.

Because it's defined as a resource in the template, though when the version is updated to a new one it's completely replaced.

This is a problem because the beanstalk UI makes it easy to deploy previous versions- you just select one and deploy it to the environment. But because cloudformation is destroying/creating the version each time there is only one. It's useful to have the UI fallback for tracking/redeploying previous version- even if it's mostly going to be done through CloudFormation.

I want CloudFormation to create a new version (when it changes) and leave the old one untouched- instead of destroying it.

I only want this behaviour for this one resource in the template- other resources can use the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt realize there is a CF feature for this

This works as expected

```
MyVersion:
  Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
  UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
```